# Getting android.os.SystemProperties in effecient way in Android P

Tags: android, android-ndk

With Android P, Non SDK interfaces have been deprecated. (link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces)
In our older code, we were using, "android.os.SystemProperties" in the following way,

```
String countryCode = null;
        try
        {
            Class<?> cl;
            cl = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
           Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class);
            countryCode = (String) method.invoke(null, "ro.csc.countryiso_code");
        return 
      }
```

Since we cannot use it this way anymore, I am now trying to get the same value in the following way,

```
String propertyValue = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
       Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + key);
       reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        propertyValue = reader.readLine().trim();
```

Although this is a standard way it is very slow, as you can see it is creating a new process and then running the shell command getprop and so on.
My question is, is there any better way to get these properties?

Answer (score 0):

Try to load all prop to a list in /system/build.prop when app started.
And search in this list.
The only thing to worry about is the permission problem and selinux.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use reflection?

You can get the country ISO code like this:

```
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager

val telephonyManager = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
val iso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getSimCountryIso()

> Returns the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.
>
> The ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 country code is provided in lowercase 2 character format.

Comment: YOu can take your phone to a different country and then this might not give the correct results. What I wanted the information that is set by either manufacturer. Basically region wise SKU.